# After installing Postfix, why doesn't it pop up the configuration interface

Tags: postfix

When I first time install Postfix, after install, an interface would pop up and ask me which type to choose from; something like:

- Internet:
- Satellite:
- Smarthost:
- Local only:

Today I removed Postfix using:

```
sudo apt-get remove postfix
```

And I tried to install it again using:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

After install, no interface pops up.

How can I make it show up again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It didn't pop up the configuration screen as configuration of the package already existed.

To reconfigure the postfix package:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```